# Is there an automatic way to organize similar data in excel using a large dataset?

Tags: excel

I have a question regarding Excel. I have a large dataset and would like to find a way to organize my data in a way that I have similar cell values grouped together. Is this possible? Also, I have already filtered for columns of interest in my dataset.

Please find an example below of what I am trying to do:

| Distributor | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Target | watch |
| walmart | lamp |
| sobeys | watch |
| frescho | wallet |
| best buy | watch |
| staples | lamp |
| canadian tire | wallet |

Would like to turn above into:

| Distributor | Item |
| --- | --- |
| Target | watch |
| sobeys | watch |
| best buy | watch |
| walmart | lamp |
| staples | lamp |
| frescho | wallet |
| canadian tire | wallet |

Is there a way to do this automatically? Thanks!

Comment: just use the sort on the data tab.  And sort by that column.  It will put everything together.

Comment: What's the logic for that order? Why can't you sort alphabetically?

Comment: Also, did you use the FILTER() function or the Filter on the data tab?  If you used the FILTER() function can you [edit] the post to include it.

Comment: This isn't my actual dataset. I'm dealing with data that has 1K+ entries and I set filters to only include values I wanted to see, however, I was wondering if there was a way to organize an excel dataset where similar texts are grouped together as illustrated above, that do not have a logical flow to them. I.e. a distributor makes X product and another X distributor makes a similar product with the same name. I'm looking for a way to group similar products together in the original dataset without having to rely on the filter to hide or include datasets.

Comment: Then sorting the data on the correct column will group them together.